# AngularJS Jasmine Testing - return rejected promise from callFake function

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am writing some tests for an AngularJS controller. I got to a point where I want to test that a variable from the view model is assigned with a specific value when a service call fails with a rejected promise.
My code for **controller** below:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('example')
    .controller('ExampleController', ['ExampleService1', 'ExampleService2', ExampleController]);

  function ExampleController(ExampleService1, ExampleService2) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.myVariable = null;

    init();

    function init() {
      ExampleService1.callSomeMethod()
        .then(ExampleService2.callMethodThatFails)
        .then(function(result) {
          //do something with result
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          vm.myVariable = "N/A";
        })
    }
  }
})();
```

And the code for my test below:

```
// ---
//ignore test initialization for brevity
it('should set the value of myVariable to N/A', function() {
    spyOn(ExampleService2, 'callMethodThatFails').and.callFake(function(param0) {
        return getResponse(param0, null, null);
    })

    $injector.get('$controller')('ExampleController as vm', {
        '$scope': $scope
    })
    $rootScope.$apply();

    expect($scope.vm.myVariable).toBe('N/A')
})

function getResponse(param0, param1, param2) {
    var promise1 = param1 === null ? $q.reject() : $q.resolve(param1);
    var promise2 = param2 === null ? $q.reject() : $q.resolve(param2);

    if (angular.equals(param0, something1)) {
        return promise1;
    } else if (angular.equals(param0, something2)) {
        return promise2;
    } else {
        $q.reject('Some custom error message')
    }
}
```

When I debug this test everything works as expected: the catch block of my `init()` function from controller gets called and the value 'N/A' is assigned to `vm.myVariable`.
Problem is that my test fails and the code doesn't reach the `expect(...)` block. The error I get is this:

> Possibly unhandled rejection: undefined thrown

I can not understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Jasmine is not going to know when promise is going to get resolved. Look into following examples to help you implement tests with promises. http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/07/13/unit-test-promises-angualrjs-q/   http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/how-to-simulate-and-test-failing-promises-in-angular

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I managed to solve this but I have no idea why the new version is working and the old one doesn't.

I'll answer this here and hope I get some more clues from you guys. The only thing that I had to change is the `getResponse` function:

```
function getResponse(param0, param1, param2) {
    if (angular.equals(param0, something1)) {
        return param1 === null ? $q.reject() : $q.resolve(param1);
    } else if (angular.equals(param0, something2)) {
        return param2 === null ? $q.reject() : $q.resolve(param2);
    } else {
        $q.reject('Some custom error message')
    }
}
```

Basically I'm not initializing the promises before the if/else statement, but I'm just returning them inline.

Comment: For me is the same thing but somehow this solved the problem.

Comment: It is the same as far I can see. The only thing that I note is that if your code reaches the last `else` it will fail because you are not `return`ing the last `$q.reject`